# Finding an $n$ so the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ satisfies $|a_n| < 10^{-4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to find $n$ so that $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ satisfies

$$|a_n| < 10^{-4}$$

I can't find this formula in my book anywhere. It seems like it would be very time consuming to just plug in numbers because I have way more to do than just this one. How do I do this before next Monday?

Comment: I don´t understand your notation, would you mind explaining it?

Comment: It is what is provided, I don't entirely understand them either.

Comment: If $a_n$ is supposed to mean $\frac1n$, then Peter Tamaroff has completely answered the question. If $a_n$ is supposed to mean something else, then you should say what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: Ok but just saying that he has completely answered it doesn't help me understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about any $n$ such that $n>10^4$? Then $$\frac 1n <10^{-4}$$

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: What is it you don't understand?

Comment: You just rewrote what I had.

Comment: @PaulthePirate Well, the problem is pretty straightforward. You want a $n$ such that $n^{-1}<10^{-4}$. This is the same as finding $n$ such that $n>10^4$, is it not?

Comment: It isn't useful to say that the problem is straightforward, obviously I have trouble with it otherwise I wouldn't have asked. I do what you do and I get an n and it doesn't seem to work out when I plug it back in.

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work out when I plug it back in.` Elaborate.

Comment: @PaulthePirate I'm sorry about that. I was just trying to (somehow) encourage you to think about it a little more.

Comment: I do the math, and I get a value for n, I add one to it and plug it into $a_n$ and it isn't very close to $10^{-4}$ even if I subtract or add 1.

Comment: What value did you get for $n$? What did you get when you plugged it into the function $f(x)=1/x$? (How are we supposed to pinpoint where you're going wrong when you won't show us your work? This sort of information is stuff you're supposed to put into your question in the first place.)

Comment: I get n = 10 I think, let me check again. Oh I get 10,000 for this one which is correct but for the other problem I get a wrong answer.

Comment: $10$ is certainly not bigger than $10^4=1000$. The inequality $n>10^4$ means you have to pick a value for $n$ which is bigger than a thousand. | Here's how to see that $1/n<10^{-4}$ is equivalent to $10^4<n$: any inequality involving positive numbers can be multiplied by a positive number, so if we multiply the inequality $1/n<1/10^4$ by $10^4n$ we get $10^4<n$, i.e. $n>1000$.